# Is there a difference between casting an int.Parse() to long and using long.Parse?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I've just stumbled on some code where the developer used

```
fooBar((long)int.Parse(someVariable));
```

The `fooBar` function is just waiting a `long` as a parameter and use it for an SQL query.

Is there any difference between that and using `long.Parse(...)`?

Comment: I guess the difference is that int.Parse might lose precision so I think long.parse would be better

Comment: Result-wise or execution-wise?

Comment: @antisanity yeah, that's what I thought too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `long.Parse` will handle numbers that are larger than an `int`. So it's preferable, unless you want an exception if the number can't fit in an `int`.

Also the casting from the `int` to `long` is unnecessary since an implicit cast exists.

Comment: An implicit cast exists as long as the function expects a `long`.  If it expects, say, an `object`, then things get weird.

Comment: @cHao yes, but the question says it's expecting a long.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is if `someVariable` represents a value that can't fit into an `int`.

Answer (score 4):

The main difference is that with `int.Parse`, you're pretty much guaranteed a number within the range of an `int`.  If the number is outside that range, an `OverflowException` will be thrown by `int.Parse` (while `long.Parse` would happily accept it, as long as the number's within `long`'s range).

Answer (score 0):

when you use long.Parse the result of function is int64 but when you use int.Parse the result is int32.